# Up to 2 php file calls is getting old answer

Tags: php, caching, iis

If i am calling a PHP file more than 2 times (at 3rd time), i am getting a old response.

My PHP file looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
clearstatcache();

$ip = $_GET['ip'];
$port = 80; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 

        if($fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
           echo "<span style='color:green;'>OK: " . $ip. "</span>";
        } else {
           echo "<span style='color:red;  '>ERROR: " . $ip. "</span>"; 
        }

?>
```

I give a IP adress over GET variable to the script, then it will does a ping to the host.

The response in the second call within 2 seconds response the right one, up to the 3rd call i will get old responses.

I tried to fix it with `clearstatcache();` but no change.

Here is a screenshot with an exampel:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Having `error_reporting(0)` while debugging your code is pretty counter productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I added a cacherule in IIS in:

```
- IIS Manager
- Webserver
- Output caching
- new rule: .php - > No caching
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an old answer but simply an error from fsockopen. Also it is probably arbitrary how many calls it takes to return the error.
Maybe a firewall blocks too many connection attempts to your target or maybe the host just can't handle the load.

Try increasing the timeout to 2 and wait a little before hitting refresh.

If you enable error_reporting(E_ALL) you will probably see a nicer error message.

Comment: if i am activating error_reporting E_ALL, the script works good every request. Only if iam setting error_reporting to null i will get "old" response after 3rd call. Why?

Comment: PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to 1.2.3.4:80 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ping\ping.php on line 9